# Hunger Games - are Victors' children safe from the Reaping?

Tags: the-hunger-games

I've looked endlessly and haven't come to any conclusion about this, but would the victors' children in a district (if they had one or a few) be equal candidates for Reapings?

Answer (score 13):

Yes. And there's a suspicion that it may even be **MORE** than equal. This is discussed and affirmed as a fact in Book 2, "*Catching Fire*", Chapter 4:

> I wonder if President Snow will insist we have children. **If we do, they'll have to face the reaping each year**.
>
> And wouldn't it be something to see the child of not one but two victors chosen for the arena? **Victors' children have been in the ring before**. It always causes a lot of excitement and generates talk about how the odds are not in that family's favor. ***But it happens too frequently to just be about odds*. Gale's convinced the Capitol does it on purpose, rigs the drawings to add extra drama**. Given all the trouble I've caused, I've probably guaranteed any child of mine a spot in the Games.

She says similar, if less informative, thing in Book 1:

> ... I know I’ll never marry, never risk bringing a child into the world. Because if there’s one thing being a victor doesn’t guarantee, it’s your children’s safety. My kids’ names would go right into the reaping balls with everyone else’s....

Answer (score 3):

Considering how Katniss mentions a couple of times how she doesn't want to bring children into her world because they'll be subject to the same rules she's been her whole life, I'd assume they **would be** candidates for reaping, yes.